# How can you resize an image in NodeJS using Sharp having only a URL, using async/await, and without a local copy being created?

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, sharp

I'm working in an environment where the available image processing library is NodeJS's [Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) for scaling images. It has been stable as it is being pipe based, but I'm tasked with converting it into TypeScript, and set it up using Async/Await when possible. I have most of the pieces ready, but the issue I am facing lies in the fact that all I have is a URL of an image and Sharp either expects a string URI (local file only) or a Buffer.

Currently, I am using the package [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) in order to fetch the image as a string retrievable by the `data` property on the response. I've been feeding a buffer created from the string by `Buffer.from(response.data)` into Sharp, and it doesn't have any issues until I try and "work" with the image by attempting to gather the metadata. At this point it throws an error: `[Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format]`. But I know that the image is valid, as it worked in the old system, and I didn't change any dependencies.

I use QuokkaJS to test, and the following PoC fails, and I need to get it to functioning order.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Sharp from 'sharp';
const url = 'https://dqktdb1dhykn6.cloudfront.net/357882-TLRKytH3h.jpg';

const imageResponse = await axios({url: url, responseType: 'stream'});
const buffer = Buffer.from(imageResponse.data);
let src = new Sharp(buffer);
const src2 = src.clone();//this is simply because it will end up being a loop, if this is the issue let me know.
try {
    await src2.jpeg();
    await src2.resize(null, 1920);
    await src2.resize(1080, null);
    const metadata = await src2.clone().metadata();//this is where it fails
    console.log(metadata);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);//logs the mentioned error
}
```

If anybody has any idea what I am doing incorrectly, or has anything specific information that they would like me to add, please let me know! If I ***need*** to pipe the image data, let me know. I've tried to directly pipe it getting a `pipe is not a function` on the string (which makes sense).

Update #1:

A big thank you to @Thee_Sritabtim for the comment, which solved the issue. Basically, I had been trying to convert a Stream based String into a Buffer. I needed to instead declare that the request was for an `ArrayBuffer`, and then feed it into Sharp while declaring its type of `binary`. The working example of the PoC is below!

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Sharp from 'sharp';
const url = 'https://dqktdb1dhykn6.cloudfront.net/357882-TLRKytH3h.jpg';

const imageResponse = await axios({url: url, responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
const buffer = Buffer.from(imageResponse.data, 'binary');
let src = new Sharp(buffer);
try {
    await src.jpeg();
    await src.resize(null, 1920);
    await src.resize(1080, null);
    const metadata = await src.metadata();//this was where it failed, but now it prints an object of metadata
    console.log(metadata);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);//Doesn't catch anything any more!
}
```

Comment: sharp also accepts stream. And I don't think you can get a buffer from stream like this `Buffer.from(respose.data)`. Try `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` and `Buffer.from(imageResponse.data, 'binary')` instead

Comment: This was exactly the issue. It is fixed by those 2 small changes! Feel free to add an answer so that I can select it, but either way, thank you, @TheeSritabtim!

Comment: I've added an answer with an alternative method using stream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a buffer from a `axios` response, you'll have to set `responseType` to `'arraybuffer'`.

```
const imageResponse = await axios({url: url, responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
const buffer = Buffer.from(imageResponse.data, 'binary')
```

**Alternatively,**

You could also use stream as input for `sharp()`, so you could keep the `responseType` to `'stream'`

```js
const imageResponse = await axios({url: url, responseType: 'stream'})

const src = imageResponse.data.pipe(sharp())
//...
const metadata = await src.metadata()
```

Comment: I went the 'arraybuffer` route. I was hoping to avoid piping already, so unless there's a noticeable performance penalty, I'm going to stick to the first option. Thank you again, @TheeSritabtim!