# How to Process Uploaded Image with Graphql Apollo with SharpJS in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, sharp

I have a graphql mutation that gets an image from the frontend, and that then is processed and optimized on my server.

But I can't figure out how to pass my image to sharp.

Here is my code:

```js
const Mutation = {
    createImage: async (_, { data }) => {
        const { file } = data
        const image = await file

        console.log(image)

        const sharpImage = sharp(image)
    }
}
```

I know the code doesn't work and `sharp` throws an error saying that the input is invalid. So how can I work with `createReadStream` and to create an instance of `sharp`?

When I `console.log(image)`, here is what I see:

```
image {
  filename: 'image.png',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: stream != buffer ?

Comment: @xadm Thanks for your input. I know that stream is not a buffer. I was just trying to provide some example to work with. I am trying to understand how to use `createReadStream` and process the image with `sharp`

Comment: check args ... file is ready as awaited (and if passed corectly, of course) ... console.log image or file ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61452904/6124657

Comment: @xadm when I pass the awaited file result to sharp, I still get `[Error: Input file is missing]`.I added the result of the `console.log` of the awaited file to my question

Comment: it seams you can use stream ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61786860/6124657

Comment: @xadm thanks for your help! I researched a lot and eventually found all the pieces that made my graphql resolver work. I posted my answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out the solution to my question.

First, I found out that I needed to add `scalar Upload` to `typeDefs`.

Then, I need to add a resolver for `Upload` like this:

```js
const { GraphQLUpload } = require('graphql-upload');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  resolvers: {
    Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  }
})
```

Then in my resolver, here is what I had to do:

```js
// this is a utility function to promisify the stream and store the image in a buffer, which then is passed to sharp
const streamToBuffer = (stream) => {
    const chunks = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
        stream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
        stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
    })
}

const Mutation = {
    createImage: async (_, { data }) => {
        const { file } = data
        const { createReadStream } = await file

        const imageBuffer = await streamToBuffer(createReadStream())

        const sharpImage = sharp(imageBuffer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apollo recommends using signed URLs rather than uploading files via mutations. https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/file-uploads/file-upload-best-practices/

This is due to CSRF risks and performance impacts, especially as an app scales. For an app which properly handles the CSRF risks, uploading a file via a mutation should be fine.